# Hinting of multidimentional array in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, type-hinting

Is it possible to phpstorm hint multidimentional arrays?

```
class myClass
{
    private $config = array(
        'var1' => array(
            1 => array(
                'name' => 'us'
            )
        )
    );
    public function Func() {
        $this->config['var1']; //I have hinting
        $this->config['var1'][]; //No hinting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6845 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.